# Mod Rewrite or Mod Proxy setup for tomcat and apache

Tags: mod-rewrite, mod-proxy

Assuming I have a domain name called "stackoverflow.com"

I have apache tomcat 7 running an application with context root as /mainsite
I can access this locally as http://stackoverflow.com:8080/mainsite
Apache tomcat is running on 8080 port.

I have apache web server running two more PHP applications on port number 80
one of the Apache application is blog
antoher apache application is forum

my url to access blog is "https://stackoverflow.com/blog"
my url to access forum is "https://stackoverflow.com/forum"

I want to send all requests with url like https://stackoverflow.com/* to mainsite on tomcat
Any url with https://stackoverflow.com/blog or https://stackoverflow.com/forum to be served by apache.

Please let me know how to do this.

I tried some thing like this in httpd.conf
but it is sending every call made to /mainsite.

```
ProxyPass /blog https://stackoverflow.com/wordpress-3.8.2/wordpress/
ProxyPassReverse /blog https://stackoverflow.com/wordpress-3.8.2/wordpress/


ProxyPass /forum http://localhost/phpBB3/
ProxyPassReverse /forum http://localhost/phpBB3/

ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/mainsite/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/mainsite/
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Do the others work if you remove the last two lines? Proxying the root directory could be a problem, because that also includes the subdirs. I suggest you rewrite the last lines to

```
ProxyPass /mainsite http://localhost:8080/mainsite/ 
ProxyPassReverse /mainsite http://localhost:8080/mainsite/
```

And then add a permanent redirect in the index.html of the apache running at port 80.